# Is there a way to track a specific dns request back to the app making it?

Tags: ubuntu, dns, webserver

My firewall has been flagging my ubuntu webserver as making `A` record dns requests to a `.su` domain which it thinks could be malware related.

I did a `tcpdump` on port 53 on the server for a few days until the domain request popped up again (because the downstream firewall doesn't record the actual URL), and now have the actual domain being requested. I looked it up and it is in a few RBLs, but I'd like to know what on my server is making those specific DNS queries.

It's not a desktop environment, it's a command line Ubuntu Server. Its running `ISPConfig`, mostly as a basic webserver, so the requests could be coming from anything installed. Maybe the OS or components trying to connect to their owner's update servers, incoming mail lookups, etc... but these are `NS` and `A` record requests only for this domain, no `MX` or `TXT` or anything else... it's really infuriating.

Any idea on how to find out what process is invoking Bind to look this domain up?

Answer (score 2):

This is crude, but you can use `iptables` to watch for the packet, and then `lsof` to find what is using the port that made the query.

Basically this:

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -p UDP --dport 53 -m string --algo bm --string foobar.su -j LOG --log-uid --log-prefix FOOBAR_MATCH

journalctl -t kernel -f | perl -ne '/FOOBAR_MATCH/ && /SPT=(\d+)/ && system("lsof -i udp:$1")'
```

^ Change `foobar.su` to whatever it is you're watching for.

If your system is IPv6 enabled, you'll need to take that `iptables` command and run it a second time as `ip6tables` instead.

Once done, run the `iptables` command again, but with `-D` instead of `-I` to delete the rule(s).

The `--log-uid` on the `iptables` rule is optional. I included it in case for some reason the `lsof` isn't able to capture the process, then you can still glean some potentially useful information.

You might also need to add another iptables rule to drop the request. Otherwise the application might get a response and disappear too fast for the `lsof` to catch it.

Comment: dude that's brillant! thanks... waiting for it to happen again! thanks!